# "Error evaluating parameter 'Gain' in..." Simulink Error

Tags: model, simulink

I have a problem in Simulink with the following error: "error evaluating parameter 'Gain' in ... In my model, I have this gain block after a MUX with two inputs. I tried all the options in the 'Multiplication' tab, but with no results. Could you help me with this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: What gain value did you enter into the mask of the gain block? Some expression?

Comment: In Matlab I've put the value 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use th block "Gain", whose gain is a vector ["your gain" "your gain"].[image]